# htaccess redirect files with the same name to just one file (been hacked)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like your help to modify my `.htaccess` file. My site has been hacked and the malware has created thousands of pages and has really hurt my rankings. I have deleted the pages, but I want all of those links to redirect to one 404 page.

What do I need to write in `.htaccess` in order to redirect all of the pages that contain a certain word?

I have tried this

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(theword)`

`RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/404.php [R=301,L]`

But it doesn't seem to work: the 404 page I created appears, but the link still remains in the browser, just that now it's like this

`http://example.com/404.php?theword=blablabla`

Maybe because my site is on a wordpress platform?

I want all the pages that start with `?theword=` to be redirected entirely and for the new link to appear `/404.php` not `/404.php?theword=`

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [QSD] (query string discard) flag added to your RewriteRule will drop the query string.

Comment: Thank you!!
Any idea on what to put in .htaccess so that the same files return a noindex and a 410?
Would this work?
<IfModule mod_headers.c> 
<FilesMatch "^?theword?$"> Header set X-Robots-Tag: "noindex, nofollow" 
</FilesMatch> </IfModule>